# Understanding Suspense and React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-suspense

I'm struggling to find problems with using **Suspense** and **React hooks**.

There are several **key problems** with the React code below.

```
import { Suspense, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const SuspensefulUserProfile = ({ userId }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserProfile(userId).then((profile) => setData(profile));
  }, [userId, setData])
  return (
    <Suspense>
      <UserProfile data={data} />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
const UserProfile = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <h2>{data.email}</h2>
    </>
  );
};
const UserProfileList = () => {
  <>
    <SuspensefulUserProfile userId={1} />
    <SuspensefulUserProfile userId={2} />
    <SuspensefulUserProfile userId={3} />
  </>
};
```

Let me know what they are.

I found two key problems.

- Misuse of `setdata` in `useEffect` dependency array
- Didn't provide `suspense` `fallback` props.

I think there is still one key problem remaining.

One weird thing is why `userId` needs to be included in the dependency array.

Comment: I found suspense is an [experimental](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) feature!

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: @Mordechai this is a job interview question. I found 2 key problems. But they said one still remained.

Comment: FYI, whether or not `setData` is in the dependencies list makes no difference. It's memoized by `useState()` already so it doesn't need to be reference-checked by React on each render of the component instance. However, allowing it to be reference-checked does not affect the behavior of the component. So your first found key "problem" isn't really a problem, it's just a redundancy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You misused `Suspense` to its core, at least until suspense for data fetching is available.

Suspense only currently works with `React.lazy` components, not with arbitrary 'loading' states of your application. For instance, how should React figure out that your `data` is loading?

The only use for `Suspense` is to allow showing some fallback while React loads a *lazy component*. For other types of lazy loading app data you can implement your own fallback, as in:

```js
const SuspensefulUserProfile = ({ userId }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserProfile(userId).then(setData);
  }, [userId])

  return data ? <UserProfile data={data} /> : 'Loading...';
};
```

Answer (score 7):

The main issue is that you need to use what's called a [**Suspense integration**](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html#what-is-suspense-exactly) in order to perform the data fetching and interface with the `<Suspense>` component.

Typically the `<UserProfile>` component would [consume a resource *synchronously*](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html#approach-3-render-as-you-fetch-using-suspense) (your `data` in this case) and *suspend* the component when the resource is not available yet, causing the `<Suspense>` to temporarily render its `fallback` prop (which you haven't specified). When the resource becomes available, the `<UserProfile>` will re-render, and the consumed resource is returned synchronously.

I've published a Suspense integration called [`suspense-service`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/suspense-service) that lets you consume resources defined by an async function using a service that encapsulates the React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Here's a demonstration of `suspense-service` below by slightly modifying your example code:

```js
// import { Fragment, Suspense } from 'react';
const { Fragment, Suspense } = React;
// import { createService, useService } from 'suspense-service';
const { createService, useService } = SuspenseService;

const fetchUserProfile = userId => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000 + Math.random() * 1000);
  }).then(() => {
    return {
      name: `User ${userId}`,
      email: `user${userId}@example.com`
    };
  });
};

const UserProfileService = createService(fetchUserProfile);

const SuspensefulUserProfile = ({ userId }) => {
  return (
    <UserProfileService.Provider request={userId}>
      <Suspense fallback={<h1>Loading User Profile...</h1>}>
        <UserProfile />
      </Suspense>
    </UserProfileService.Provider>
  );
};

const UserProfile = () => {
  const data = useService(UserProfileService);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>{data.name}</h1>
      <h2>{data.email}</h2>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

const UserProfileList = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <SuspensefulUserProfile userId={1} />
      <SuspensefulUserProfile userId={2} />
      <SuspensefulUserProfile userId={3} />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<UserProfileList />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/suspense-service@0.2.3"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```